# PHP mail error message on gmail body

Tags: php, gmail, opencart

i'm working on an Opencart project. There i'm using php mail function to send email. When i send that email i'm getting an error message on my gmail mail body.

Here i have attached an image of that error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABJly.png)

So could you please give me a solution for this issue.

Comment: Click on learn more and investiage gmail rules and experiment with your mail, try to change it

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending your email by the default `mail()` function in PHP, it will not be trusted by most of the email clients.

What you should do instead:
Grab the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) Class and send your email through an SMTP server. If you haven't got an own email adress, you can use sites like [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/feature/smtp-relay/) which provide free SMTP server for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart has a mailer class. Why you don't use it? it is pretty simple to use. First set you SMTP configuration in admin panel SMTP setting. Then try this way:

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

$mail->setTo('SENDER EMAIL');
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject('MAIL SUBJECT');
$mail->setText('YOUR MESSAGE');
$mail->send();
```